# Tag addition requests

Tags: feature-request, tagging, tags

#### Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair

- Thoughts on adding the following tag?

  - `Custom` :: Perfect way to catagorize "Performance" or "Modifications" it can be added to a tag list with Engine / Audio / Suspension / Body Work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tag sounds too broad.  I look to the tags to indicate "all of these questions are like the others in the same set."  If I clicked the custom tag, what set of questions would I see?  Everything about custom bodywork combined with custom audio combined with custom upholstery stitching?

Looking at it another way: which of these are custom?

1. I replaced my shocks with OEM equivalents but not identical parts.
2. I replaced my axle-back exhaust with a stainless steel equivalent part.
3. I retuned my ECU but left all original equipment in place.
4. I replaced my up-pipe with a free-er flowing unit.
5. I replaced my tires with a different brand of all-weathers.